# OpenUI5 routing and authentication

Tags: sapui5

I need to implement a comprehensive security environment for my OpenUI5 application. I generate `session_id` and `user_id` on server-side and keep them on both server-side (in the database) and client-side (in `sessionStorage`). The fact that session storage is destroyed on tab/page closing is an advantage in this case.

At `onBeforeRendering` event I asynchronously check if `session_id` and `user_id` that I have on client-side match those on server-side.

```js
onBeforeRendering: function () {

    let currView = this;

    checkSession(sessionStorage.getItem("SessionId"),
        sessionStorage.getItem("UserId"), function (response) {
            if (!response.result) {
                let oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(currView);
                oRouter.navTo("login");
            }
        });
}
```

This pattern doesn’t really allow me to achieve what I need. Since I do the check asynchronously the client-side has enough time to render the view and the view is shown for a second and then user redirected to the login page.

Moreover, if I copy internal URL (http://myapp:3000/#/productList), close the tab and then paste the URL to a new tab, a user is redirected back to the login page but then he can click browser’s back button and it takes him to the internal page.

I managed to prevent this behavior partially by implementing the same `checkSession` function on an `onRoutePatternMatched` event, but then I face the same issue: the page is presented to the user for a second then routes him back to the login page.

My other approach was to handle navigation events, but I don't know how to spot the login page in a single-page application.

```js
$(window).on("navigate", handleNavigate);
function handleNavigate() {
    let path = window.location.pathname;
    alert(path);
}
```

**My question:**
How to prevent user from accessing internal pages when session storage is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an event that is triggered every time you get an HTTP error code from the server. It’s the `requestFailed` of the `oDataModel` (https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel)

I imagine, when everytime you load a page a request is being sent to the server? And if you don’t have the correct session info, you get a 401 correct? If that’s the case, you can listen to that event and do whatever you want when a 401 gets returned.

If you are using jQuery to fetch the data, the same result can be obtained with [`ajaxError`](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/#ajaxError-handler).

Comment: That's not my case. I don't work with ODataModel. I fetch data with asynchronous request form my DB and then bind the data to the View

Comment: jquery ajax,  right? Just edited my answer. Cheers!

Comment: no, I don't get 401, since I don't use user-level authentication on CRUD operations